# Difference between 2 different nested hash in Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, nested-attributes, ruby-on-rails-2

Consider the Following nested Hash:

```
data1 = {
  "3"=>{"passenger_type"=>"ADT", "the_order"=>"3", "last"=>"JONES", "first"=>"ALENA", "middle"=>nil}, 
  "2"=>{"passenger_type"=>"ADT", "the_order"=>"2", "last"=>"JONES", "first"=>"MAXIM", "middle"=>nil}, 
  "1"=>{"passenger_type"=>"ADTT", "the_order"=>"1", "last"=>"JONES", "first"=>"TODD", "middle"=>nil}}


data2 = {
   "3"=>{"first"=>"ALENA", "the_order"=>"3", "middle"=>"", "passenger_type"=>"ADTT", "last"=>"JONES"}, 
   "2"=>{"first"=>"MAXIM", "the_order"=>"2", "middle"=>"", "passenger_type"=>"ADT", "last"=>"JONES"}, 
   "1"=>{"first"=>"TODD", "the_order"=>"1", "middle"=>"", "passenger_type"=>"ADT", "last"=>"JONESS"}}
```

The Output Should be like this(difference between both hash listed values):

```
{"3" => {"passenger_type" => ["ADT", "ADTT"]}, 
 "1" => {"passenger_type" => ["ADTT", "ADT"], "last" => ["JONES", "JONESS"]}
```

Anyone your suggestion is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean for the key `middle` to have the same values in `data1` and `data2` (i.e, all `''` or all `nil`)?  If that's an oversight, no reply needed; I'll delete this comment after your edit...

Comment: In that case I don't understand why `middle=>[nil,'']` does not appear in your desired output.  Please clarify by editing (rather than in a comment).

Comment: If the value is same then that value will not be get returned, only the different value  will be returned with key which if it does not match in between data1 and data2

Comment: If any field is blank for example: "middle" in both data1 and data2 then it will not be returned in output.

Comment: So 'nil' and `''` are being treated as the same value for the purpose of the inclusion/exclusion criteria?

Comment: I am handling it though code, if in any hash field is ""(blank), I am converting it to nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the form of [Hash#merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that takes a block to produce the desired result in a compact manner:

```
data1.merge(data2) { |_,ho,hn|
       ho.merge(hn) { |_,o,n| (o==n||o==''||n=='') ? nil : [o,n] }
         .delete_if { |_,v| v==nil } }
     .delete_if { |_,v| v.empty? }
  #=> {"3"=>{"passenger_type"=>["ADT", "ADTT"]},
  #    "1"=>{"passenger_type"=>["ADTT", "ADT"], "last"=>["JONES", "JONESS"]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ugly code:

```
data3 = {}
data1.each do |k, v|
  v2 = data2[k]
  v.each do |item, val|
    if v2.has_key?(item) then
      if (val == nil or val == '') and (v2[item] == nil or v2[item] == '') then
        next
      end

      if val != v2[item] then
        data3[k] ||= {}
        data3[k][item] = [val, v2[item]]
      end
    end
  end
end

puts data3
```

prints

```
{"3"=>{"passenger_type"=>["ADT", "ADTT"]}, "1"=>{"passenger_type"=>["ADTT", "ADT"], "last"=>["JONES", "JONESS"]}}
```

Comment: don't know the topic starter's requirements, so just as a warning: this won't handle the case when data1 has less keys then data2. also won't work for deeper-nested hashes.

Comment: this is also helpfull Fabricator,